# Avoiding 304 (not modified) responses

Tags: apache, http, http-status-codes, http-status-code-304

Is it an `ExpiresDefault` Apache directive enough to avoid HTTP Status 304 responses from the server? I have set `ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"` but I'm still seeing log entries with a 304 response for `"GET /assets/template/default/css/style.min.css?v=1 HTTP/1.1"` whenever I open any page on a local [PHPMyFAQ](http://www.phpmyfaq.de/) site. Emptying the browser cache doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Expires:` header your server sends out has nothing to do with future 304 responses. It provides only an estimate to clients/proxies for how long they can wait before considering a resource "stale." Clients aren't *required* to observe this header and are free to continue making new requests for the same resource if they wish. So, to answer your question in short:

> No, you'll never be able to explicitly prevent users from making new requests for the same resource regardless of what headers you send.

The 304 response is the result of a matching `If-Match` or `If-Modified-Since` header in the client request. What's happening here is your server is sending out either/or/both of the following headers with its original response:

- `ETag`
- `Last-Modified`

Clients then send back the following headers with their requests to see if the resource has changed from their cached version:

- `If-Match` (ETag)
- `If-Modified-Since` (Last-Modified)

If either of these conditions is true then the server will send the `304 Not Modified` response you've observed and the client will know it can safely serve up its cached version of the resource.

**Compliance Note**

RFC 2616 [Section 14.21](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) actually prohibits compliant servers from sending `Expires` headers more than one year in the future, so you shouldn't be using *"access plus 10 years"* in the first place:

> HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD NOT send Expires dates more than one year in the future.

Comment: SHOULD NOT !== MUST NOT (not prohibited, just not recommended: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt)