# iOS Safari 304 caching bug - Blank pages

Tags: ios, flask, safari, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I've recently launched my web app, a simple video sharing website. It seems to work well on all Desktop browsers and any phone except the iPhone. I've tested it with friends and family and some iPhone users get a blank screen and sometimes their browser crashes.

I'm not using any plugins or flash. Back-end: Flask, sqlite Front-end: JS, Jquery, Bootstrap.

The website is: www.mntshr.com

I initially suspected this was something to do with the website's cache behaviour, but it all seems normal. After plenty of googling, I've found several articles discussing a 304 bug in Safari. Like these: 
[link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140929155404-50035345-the-infamous-safari-304-bug-is-still-there-in-yosemite-and-ios-8), [link](http://tech.vg.no/2013/10/02/ios7-bug-shows-white-page-when-getting-304-not-modified-from-server/).

I've disabled caching on my website for now; it seems to be working now.
Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Any known fixes?

Comment: @brianKH I created a new post with more detailed information regarding the problem.

Comment: Is your web server responding with 304? You should verify that before assuming that's the cause. You can verify that in your web server access log. If you don't use 304, then that's not the cause.

Comment: Also, is the crash happening on the home page, or on a different page?

Comment: The crash is occurring on the main page, and the web server was responding with a 304 for several items on the page.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Safari's issues (since I don't use it myself), but you can configure your web server to not respond with 304. If you use apache, you might find this useful (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383125/avoiding-304-not-modified-responses).

Comment: another reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811286/nodejs-express-cache-and-304-status-code