# Safari fails to load a cached resource when receiving a 304 response

Tags: rust, safari, http2, actix-web

I originally posted the question on the [Actix discussion boards](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/discussions/1993) over at GitHub, but I think it may get a bit more exposure in SO, so here it goes.

So, I have a setup like this:

```rust
// --snip--
.wrap(DefaultHeaders::new().header("cache-control", "public, max-age=5, must-revalidate"))
.service(
    actix_files::Files::new("/", &settings.server.public_dir)
        .index_file(&settings.server.index_file)
)
// --snip--
```

If I run my server without SSL, it defaults to HTTP/1.1 and so when I make a request (any browser) to a static file, for example `app.js`, everything works as I would expect. The server returns a 200 status with the correct file and the correct caching header along with an `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers. Etags and last modified are enabled by default.

If I make a subsequent request in less than 5 seconds, there is no surprise either - the browsers don't attempt a new request because they have cached the file for 5 seconds.

When I make another request in more than 5 seconds, browsers would correctly send conditional requests to the server, including an `if-none-match` header with the expected etag value for `app.js` and the server would correctly return a `304 Not Modified` response without actually sending the file in the body of the response.

```
RESPONSE: Ok(
ServiceResponse HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
  headers:
    "last-modified": "Mon, 08 Feb 2021 14:56:48 GMT"
    "accept-ranges": "bytes"
    "cache-control": "public, max-age=5, must-revalidate"
    "content-encoding": "gzip"
    "content-type": "image/jpeg"
    "etag": "\"c55582f:11923:60215130:4678e1d\""
    "content-disposition": "inline; filename=\"test.jpeg\""
  body: Stream
)
```

There are no surprises here either as this behaviour is exactly what I expect to happen. The problem is when I enable SSL and my server starts returning streaming bodies over HTTP/2.

Chrome and Firefox browsers behave the exact same way as before, requesting the resource again if the subsequent request is made after 5 seconds and when a 304 response is received, they simply load my `app.js` from their caches.

Safari (both on macos and iOS), on the other hand, has absolutely no clue how to deal with the 304 response. It does correctly send the if-none-match and since-last-modified headers, but when actix replies with 304, it can't load my static file.

The Network tab doesn't help either:

[image: safari network tab is useless]

Where it says "No response headers" is obviously BS, since I can debug the headers in Actix and see they are in fact correct:

```
RESPONSE: Ok(
ServiceResponse HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
  headers:
    "last-modified": "Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:54:28 GMT"
    "accept-ranges": "bytes"
    "content-encoding": "br"
    "content-type": "application/javascript"
    "etag": "\"a352043:2db3:60290164:2f00192\""
    "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"VideoPlayer.js\""
  body: Stream
)
```

I'm noticing that on the first request to the file when the browser hasn't cached it, the response is a HTTP/2, but the response to the conditional request is a HTTP/1.1 as you can see in the excerpt above.

Been stuck on this one for a while how, so any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be a 304 issue with Safari: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281359/ios-safari-304-caching-bug-blank-pages

Answer (score 0):

I think it's likely related to a 304 response with an empty chunked body (it's not technically correct and Safari seems to be stricter in what it accepts), I've seen this issue elsewhere: https://github.com/RipcordSoftware/AvanceDB/issues/29#issuecomment-275071917

It looks like recent versions of actix-files are trying to fix 304 issues, eg. https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/9bdd334bb4687170351d6bfcbbde756eaeaffa0a/actix-files/CHANGES.md?plain=1#L9 and https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/812